# How can we call Nextjs API from Nextjs Pages?

Tags: javascript, next.js, response, nextjs-dynamic-routing, getserversideprops

I want to load data on the home page for which I've written an API in nextjs project. I am able to call that api at client side using useEffect but I want to load the data at server side only so I was trying to call the api from getServerSideProps.
My question here is that is this possible? calling the api from getServerSideProps as I was getting error when I use fetch and deploy it.
and If I directly try to use the api function inside getServerSideProps then it says that the status

This is the code I am using
[image: Code Image]
This is the error I am getting
[image]

If I try to use statusCode instead of status then also it throws error
[image]

Comment: What version of NextJS are you on?

Comment: Nextjs 14.1 and using page based routing

Comment: Only thing I can think of at the moment is maybe getServerSideProps gets executed in an edge runtime and not NodeJS runtime. Do you know what runtime is your app using, is it NodeJS or Edge?